# overriding modelform choices with __init__

Tags: python, django, overriding, modelform

I've been trying to get the fields for a choice to change based on what i give it in my view and i get

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

here is my view.py

```
def CarOwnerSearch(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = carOwnerForm.__init__(self,'B','None','C')
        return render (request,'carmanager/CarOwnerSearch.html', {'form': form})
```

OK ive got a modelform

```
class carOwnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.charfield()
    last_name = forms.charfield()

    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        super(carOwnerForm,self).__init(a,b,c)
        self.field["ownership_Type"].choice = [a,b,c]

    class Meta:
        model = CarOwner
        fields = ['ownership_type','CarModel']
```

and this is my model.py

```
class CarOwner(models.Model):
    ownershipTpes_choices = ( ('R','Rented'),('L','Leased'),('O','Owned'))
    ownership_Type = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                                     choices=ownershipTypeChoices)
```

the traceback is here 
this is an edit update for a particular problem noted in the comments

Comment: Well, indeed `self` is not defined in that function. Why do you think it should be? Why are you calling `__init__` directly at all?

Comment: i first tried it without the self but it was asking for a 3rd arguement 
so i added self. in the model.py there are choices but for a view i dont want those choices to appear i want different choices to appear so im trying to override the choices for that field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would be initializing the form:

```
form = carOwnerForm.__init__(self,'B','None','C')
```

should be

```
form = carOwnerForm('B', None, 'C')
```

Comment: ok that solved it now i getting a new error 

    'str' object has no attribute 'get'
    AttributeError

Comment: i would need more context. Can you look into the stacktrace and see where it is failing ? Also, you might have conflicting local variable names in your declarations